# C# one event with multiple subscribers issues with ordering

Tags: c#, events

I have a class , lets call it class A . Class A has an event "OnSendData" . And there is another class named B . Class A has an arraylist with references of class B . Class A create instances of class B when something happens and add them to its arraylist . In class B constructor i have a code like this :

```
Public B (A parent)
{ Parent.OnSendData += parent_OnSendData; }
```

When i invoke class A event , my event subscribers calls in order of subscribtion . I dont want this , i want them all to notify at once . 
What should i do for this to happen ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you're raising the event, you can call [`Delegate.GetInvocationList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist) to get all the subscribers - and then use a separate task or thread per subscriber to call them all in parallel.

Note that your subscribers will have to be thread-safe for this to work - and neither `ArrayList` nor `List<T>` (you should be using the latter; `ArrayList` is so 2004...) are thread-safe, so you'd need extra locking etc.